# what to choose from website, cloud service & virtual machine on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

I have already knowledge of windows azure and worked on cloud service,storage & WASD, Still there are plenty of ways to put our application on Azure including **Website, Cloud Service, Virtual Machine** so many developers have question regarding that what to choose when from above list? (Like me)

My purpose of this question is just expert guys of Azure can differentiate these terminology and **In which situation what is best suitable one**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this blog post sums it all up nicely: 'Windows Azure Websites, Web Roles, and VMs: When to use which?'

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/06/27/windows-azure-websites-web-roles-and-vms-when-to-use-which.aspx